# Comparing Date from ORACLE db with current date

Tags: php, oracle, date

I have an issue with comparing a date from Oracle database with the current date and time
this is my query: `Select name,adress,delivery_date from business_db`
the delivery_date column shows me dates in this format: 2010-07-21 17:00:00.000

I need to show only the DB rows that are Superior to the current date

i used this to get the current date and time :

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
$date = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

and tried to compare dates with a simple " where delivery_date > $date "
but it didn't work

Thank you

Comment: `'dd-mm-YYYY HH:mi:ss'` appears to be a valid format where as  ('d-m-Y H:i:s'); doesn't appear to be.  so `Select name,adress,delivery_date from business_db WHERE delivery_date>=to_date('2016-07-21 17:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')`

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP but I don't think there is any automatic conversion between PHP and Oracle dates, so you will need to check exactly what SQL sees when you pass an PHP date and what factors can influence it on both sides, such as `nls_date_format`.

Comment: Why not use `current_date` in the query and get oracle to do that bit?

Comment: @xQbert Thanks for the answer, but i' trying to compare the delivery_date field to the current date(the system date) not 2016-07-21..., but as you can see the output of the query show also 3 digits of milliseconds that would make it harder to compare the two

Comment: @WilliamRobertson thank you

Comment: @EdHeal, i don't really know how to do it, can you show me the syntax if it's possible.

Comment: Remove `$date`  replace with above

Comment: @EdHeal should i replace it with "current_date" ?

Comment: Yes. Try it. Get the db to do the work

Comment: Did you try to convert you `$date` by this function `to_date`? if no, then do try it like: `where delivery_date > to_date ($date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sysdate

```
select Select name,adress,delivery_date from business_db
    where to_date('08.08.2017 12:30','DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') > sysdate;
```

sysdate is the oracle system date in DATE format.

with php variable it should be something like that

php part :

```
$date = '08.08.2017 12:30';
```

sql part :

```
select Select name,adress,delivery_date from business_db
    where to_date($date,'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') > sysdate;
```